# Android: Html.fromHtml() method not working with standard Html tags

Tags: android, html

So I have an HTML string I want to display as styled text in a textview but it never seems to work. My HTML string uses tags which are supposed to be supported by the fromHtml() method but it never displays the text properly, just returns the original HTML string. Here's an example of my HTML:

```
<div class="className"><p>Sample text <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a></p></div>
```

Nothing special as you can see, yet it never parses it correctly. Could it be that the method doesn't support the "class" attribute? If so, how do I add support for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class provides limited to support of HTML elements. And "class" attributes are not supported.

To understand which tags can be used and how they will be rendered refer to [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/text/Html.java#HtmlToSpannedConverter.handleStartTag%28java.lang.String%2Corg.xml.sax.Attributes%29) (android 5.0.1 r1). You can provide custom [TagHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler%29) or use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display complex HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this lib: https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview
It supports several tags more than native Html.fromHtml in Android.